# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection\\AbstractDb::setConnection() must implement interface

Tags: magento2

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb::setConnection() must
>   implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface,
>   boolean given, called in
>   /var/www/stg.bulk.ls1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/Collection/AbstractCollection.php
>   on line 124 and defined in
>   /var/www/stg.bulk.ls1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:183\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/stg.bulk.ls1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(124):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->setConnection(false)\n#1
>   /var/www/stg.bulk.ls1/public_html/app/code/FishPig/WordPress/Model/ResourceModel/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query),
>   Object(Mag in
>   /var/www/stg.bulk.ls1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php
>   on line 183

Comment: Is it default magento installation?

Comment: when this error occurred?

Comment: when update from magento 2.2.1 to 2.2.7 error show

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the FishPig_WordPress integration module being enabled, but the associated WordPress database is not available. If you've downloaded a copy of a website with this enabled without the attached WordPress site database - your site front-end can likely crash if it's using widgets associated with FishPig_WordPress.

You have two options:

1. If you're just using the site locally for development, you can disable the module using `php bin/magento module:disable FishPig_WordPress`. Re-compile and clear the cache afterward.
2. Find the missing WordPress database and set it up - if you're not sure where the Wordpress site is installed, you can find it's relative path by using the following SQL query `SELECT * FROM db.core_config_data WHERE`path`= 'wordpress/setup/path';`. From there - you can find the necessary details in the wp-config.php to help locate your missing database.